# The same validation for multiple views in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, api-design

I have created a number of API endpoints for accepting POST requests using DjangoRestFramework. For 5/6 of them, I need to have 1 key in the body present providing some data so for each view I have

```
if (key not in request.data):
  return Response('please provide key', status=400)
```

How can I remove this duplication across all views?

Comment: use [serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a common function in a different file and import that function in your views.py which will validate for each view whether in request body key is passed or not.

*Your common function will look like this*
common.py

```
def get_key(request):
    if (key not in request.data):
        return Response('please provide key', status=400)
    return request.data
```

*And your views will look like this.*
views.py

```
from .common import get_key

    @api_view(['GET'])
    def userDetail(request,pk):
        key = get_key(request) #calling the function to check for key
        if key:
            users = User.objects.get(id=pk)
            serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here I am assuming you are using a function-based view if you are using class-based view approach will be the same.

Hope it helps. Happy learning.